# how to bypass the messaging.requestPermission() in firebase cloud messaging

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase cloud messaging library for sending push notification on web, I dont want to show the displays a consent dialog to let users grant your app permission to receive notifications in the browser, instead i have my own function which will do the same with my custom css,Can anyone know how to bypass the messaging.requestPermission() so that it it will take permisson granted and proceed further accordingly?